# Disabling navigation bar on segue when searching

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got an iOS app that's using a table view with a search bar added to the table view. When a row is tapped, I push another view controller that shows the details of the row that was tapped.
Our table view and detail view both hide the navigation bar. 
When the search bar is not active, the navigation bar is disabled on the detail view controller, which is expected.
However, when search is active, the navigation bar shows up on the detail view controller. From what I've read, that's the default behavior for any transitions that occur when search is enabled. Is this accurate?
If so, is there anything I can do to hide the navigation bar? More generally, is there anything I can do to have the push of the detail controller behave the same way regardless of whether search is active or not?

Comment: On digging further, I'm seeing that iOS is actually replacing my navigation bar with it's own. I have a custom back button that I embed in the navigation bar, which is not visible when the segue occurs while search is active. Is this something that iOS does by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your detail view controller try putting :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```

[Link to doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setNavigationBarHidden:animated:)

Comment: I've tried that and also tried     self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES; 
Neither approach works, and the navigation bar still appears

Comment: Then you should have a side effect code. Post some so we can get further

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by side effect code?
I've commented out everything in my viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear except for the line you suggested. I also tried setting 'Top bar' in the storyboard to None. The navigation bar still appears when the search bar is active